# Fire event only on image change

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I needs to fire an event only on change of image after doing file upload.
I had written the following code. But it's firing on load of page also. I dont want onload. How can we achieve it ?

```
$(document).ready(function () {         
        $('#Imgphoto1').on('load', function () {
            alert();
            top.IsfieldChange("1");
        });
    });

 <asp:Image ID="Imgphoto1" runat="server" AlternateText="No Photo Available" ImageUrl="../Designer/Images/DefaultEmployeeImage.jpg"
                                    Width="153" Height="192" />

<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload12" runat="server" onpropertychange='return setPhoto(id);' onchange="validcheckFileExtension(this);" ToolTip="Allowed files('.jpeg', '.png', '.gif', '.jpg')" />
```

Comment: share all relevant code HTML CSS

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
 $("document").ready(function(){

$("#upload").change(function() {
    alert('changed!');
});});
```

Comment: its not firing.

Comment: which control you are using?

Comment: asp.net image control

Comment: you cannot use the image for this.

you can file upload control for this..

or else please elaborate your need ..

Comment: Whenever my image was changed I need to fire an alert.

Answer (score 0):

just use something like this

```js
$("#Imgphoto1").on('change',function() {
                alert('img uploaded');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" id="Imgphoto1">
```

Comment: this was the samething which I need. But why my code with asp control is not working ?